# Google script - setting a formula in

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm unable to write a script to put a formula in the following input

I would like to use this formula =OR(D3="George"; E3="Eric") in the filter used in my Google Sheet.

When I put manually in the filter as a condition, it's ok

When I tried to save the code, it's not saved and it's not working. I don't understand why the script is not copy/paste the text that I want to put

```
function myfunction5() { 
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    let filter = ss.getFilter(); 
    const formula = r => r[4] == "Maxime" | r[6] == "Eric";//only needs to refer to the first non header row. Rest will be applied automatically 
    const newCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria() 
      .whenFormulaSatisfied(""=OR(D3="George"; E3="Eric")"") // not working but this formula is working when I put it directly in the field in the filter in Google Sheet 
      .build(); 
    filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(3, newCriteria); 
}
```

Comment: function myfunction5() {
let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
let filter = ss.getFilter();
const formula = r => r[4] == "Maxime" | r[6] == "Eric";//only needs to refer to the first non header row. Rest will be applied automatically
const newCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
 .whenFormulaSatisfied(""=OR(D3="George"; E3="Eric")"") // not working but this formula is working when I put it directly in the field in the filter in Google Sheet
 .build(); 
filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(3, newCriteria);
}

Comment: whenFormulaSatisfied(""=OR(D3="George"; E3="Eric")"") it's this line which is not working even if the formula OR is working in the GoogleSheet

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify; code is unreadable in comments. [Edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function myfunction5() { 
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  let filter = ss.getFilter(); 
  const formula = r => r[4] == "Maxime" | r[6] == "Eric";//I don't really understand this.  I just copied it.  So hopefully you know more than me
  const newCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria() .whenFormulaSatisfied('=OR(D3="George"; E3="Eric")') 
}
```

try this for your formula

```
`=OR(D3="George"; E3="${cellule}")`//outer punctuation marks are back ticks.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working !

Now, I've tried to replace '=OR(D3="George"; E3="Eric")' by a variable called formula
let cellule = sh.getRange("D1").getValue(); // get Eric
let formula = '=OR(D3="George"; E3="'& cellule &'")'; //the contatenation is not working

Comment: please don't hesitate to let me know if a guide exist to put my code in good format instead of having a block

Comment: - [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunction() {
let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
let filter = sh.getFilter();
let cellule = sh.getRange("D1").getValue();
let newCriteria;
newCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenFormulaSatisfied(`=OR(D3="${cellule}"; E3="${cellule}")`)
 .build(); 
filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(4, newCriteria);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper, it's working perfectly now. I've posted the code if anyone want to use it again

Comment: By the way, I don't understant why I have to use ` instead of " into the brackets of whenFormulaSatisfied. It's a chain of text so I don't see the difference when we are assigning a variable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).